# deliver data to cometd server using a channel

Tags: java, comet, server-push, cometd, cometserver

How can I deliver some data to server side while subscribing to server?

As an example,

When I subscribing /alert/12345, I want to send some other information such as alert_type, date_time etc to CometD server.

Comment: how you connect to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a `data` map in subscribe:

```
cometd.subscribe(channelId, undefined, callback, { data: data })
```

But as far as I could see, you can only get a reference to the data map in `org.cometd.bayeux.server.Authorizer`. I couldn't get it via `org.cometd.bayeux.server.BayeuxServer.SubscriptionListener` because there is no reference to the `ServerMessage`.

You can see my use of it here:

- https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-cometd/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/lazan/t5/cometd/PushTarget.js#L37
- https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-cometd/blob/master/src/main/java/org/lazan/t5/cometd/services/internal/AuthorizersImpl.java#L67

Comment: I filed http://bugs.cometd.org/browse/COMETD-504 to track this issue: `SubscriptionListener`s should be able to access the subscription message.

Comment: I only found this data map by looking at the javascript sources. It's probably a good idea to include a section in the docs for the data map.

Comment: Lance Java, sure. Why don't you file an issue about this at http://bugs.cometd.org ? You seem to know CometD well, so contributing back to the project in form of issue submission (http://docs.cometd.org/reference/contribute.html) will be great on the open source side of things :) Thanks !